# Is there an index of common spectral lineshapes or table of common lineshape functions?

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, data-analysis

Is there an index of common spectral lineshapes in physics? Is there a program that automatically tries fitting to many different lineshapes?

By line *shape* I mean the function that, given appropriate parameters, describes the dataset around a peak. e.g. gaussian, lorentzian, fano, etc...

You can find lots of lineshapes described all over the internet and various other resources, but they are some that you will not find unless you already kind of know what you are looking for. Say I am fitting data to find a peak. If I know what the data should look like, then I can fit the data to a formula. But say I have less than perfect knowledge of the theory around the data I am fitting. Or say that some unexpected part of my experiment is substantially impacting the lineshape. For example, suppose I am expecting a narrow gaussian peak, but my experiment's resolution is limited by some component with a lorentzian peak (or vice verse); a fit to the wrong function might produce bad results.

It would be great to have a curve-fitter that can try fitting to several different common functions, or even to have a table to check by eye and see if my lineshape is a good fit to some well-known function. Ideally, this lineshape reference would include a list of circumstances where the lineshape typically arises. It might also include images with the function displayed with various combinations of parameters - to make it easier to recognize.

Does such a tool or reference exist? If so, please let me know! If not, I would be curious to hear about any comparable substitute. Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, I am interested in line *shapes*, not the locations of the lines. That is, the mathematical equations that might describe the data (specifically around a peak). I have inserted the second paragraph in this edit and the example.

Comment: In many applications the physical line shapes tend to be simple, and the complexity arises mostly from the detector response functions and non-trivial background shapes. But response functions can be quite complicated and backgrounds are diverse.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the [HITEMP/HITRAN database](https://hitran.org/hitemp/)? Or are you looking for something different/more exotic?

Comment: Nevermind, I re-read... you're looking for something that would make *use* of HITEMP/HITRAN in order to find the temperature/species that make up a given spectrum... You may want to clarify your application. There might be a list of common spectra for, say, atmospheric measurements. But that would be very different from a list for turbulent combustion.

Comment: Not sure what your aim is here. I've had occasions where it was difficult to find a good fitting function, but since I was always interested in the line position just reading off the location of the line's peak was often sufficient for my purposes. But you say that you're only interested in the shapes and not the line positions. Don't know why you would only be interested in the shape, but if you just want to produce a curve which fits the shape of an experimental spectral line, couldn't you just run your data through some sort of low-pass digital filter algorithm?

Comment: @SamuelWeir Fair question. Short answer is that I want more precise peak fitting. I was recently taught that a peak can be resolved to a precision of R/SNR where R is the resolution of the data and SNR is the signal to noise ratio. But this rule of thumb would not be valid for peaks that are improperly fit. In the (admittedly rare) case that you have very nice data but the peak shape is not what you expect, knowing the function helps you better resolve the peak. Also, if your data is appearing in the wrong shape, identifying the shape automatically could be very useful.

Comment: So your ultimate goal is to find some way of determining peak positions to the highest possible accuracy without knowing in advance the function that describes the peak? If the SNR is very large and you only need a position accuracy of R, then of course all you need to is the find the data point with the highest value around the location of the peak and call that the peak position. If the SNR is not very large and/or you need higher accuracy than R, I think that I would just run the data through a low-pass filter and then get the peak position from the highest point of the resulting curve....

Comment: ....That, at least, is the best practical solution that I can think of offhand as an experimentalist. Probably can find some built-in functions in Mathematica and similar applications to do the low-pass digital filtering of the data to generate a smooth curve from the data points of a peak. We'll see if someone else can come up with any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A year after posting this question, I discovered [fityk](https://github.com/wojdyr/fityk) [nonlinear curve fitting software](http://fityk.nieto.pl/).

There are 32 different nonlinear fits available - everything from "SplitPseudoVoigt" to "Constant." Using fityk, it is easy to try several different lineshapes on a spectrum, and all of the lineshapes are identified by name. There is no "list of circumstances where the lineshape typically arises," but it certainly provides the main functionality I was looking for.

Fityk has many other useful features as well, and, at time of writing, it seems very well maintained.